# vba pass ActiveX contol object to module

Tags: vba, excel, controls

I've had a good scan of SO but cannot find a solution to this.

- I have a number of sheets in an Excel workbook
- Each sheet has an identical collection of ActiveX Togglebuttons
- These toggle buttons control the filtering of data in a pivot chart. 
  Filtering on "1" or "All"
- I want the toggle button to change colour when clicked.

  I have this working fine when all the code is connected with the sheet.
  Here I am passing "tgl_butt" as the button name

d

```
dim Ctrl as OLEObject
  With ActiveSheet
'
' change button colour
'
For Each Ctrl In OLEObjects
   If TypeName(Ctrl.Object) = "ToggleButton" Then
     If Ctrl.Name = Tgl_butt Then
        If BooValue = True Then
           OLEObjects(Ctrl.Name).Object.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' in = yellow
           Else
           OLEObjects(Ctrl.Name).Object.BackColor = RGB(184, 204, 228) 'out = blue
       End If
    End If
 End If
Next Ctrl
End With
```

I am now trying to put this code into a module so that it can be shared by all the worksheets containing toggle buttons.

```
Call do_filter(Tgl_but.Value, "Tgl_name",  Ctrl)
```

and then in the Module ..

```
Public Sub do_filter(BooValue As Boolean, Tgl_butt As String,Ctrl As OLEObject)

With ActiveSheet
  Dim myCtrl 'As OLEObject
   For Each myCtrl In Ctrl
      If TypeName(myCtrl.Object) = "ToggleButton" Then
         If myCtrl.Name = Tgl_butt Then
            If BooValue = True Then
               Ctrl(myCtrl.Name).Object.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' in = yellow
            Else
               Ctrl(myCtrl.Name).Object.BackColor = RGB(184, 204, 228) 'out = blue
            End If
         End If
     End If
   Next myCtrl
End With
```

I get an "Object required" error with the above code. The Ctrl object is empty ... so I suppose I've got something drastically wrong somewhere! I've tried a number of variations to this code but cannot seem to get it to work! All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

So, you initially put the code in a worksheet class, and it worked. Then you generalized it in a module and it doesn't work. Is that right?

If that's the case I reckon:

1. The code in the worksheet class can access OleObjects for that sheet.
2. The code in the module, doesn't have direct access to the OleObjects collection, since they are global for the class but not in the module..

With your code you define:

```
With ActiveSheet
```

But don't use the . part as part of the With. i.e. the With is useless since its not being used.
I think you need to qualify the object.

So I would try either ActiveSheet.OleObjects (or place a . in front of the OleObjects collection if using the With).

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks @PaulG for the note. Didn't see it until I'd found my own solution! I'm very much a beginner when it comes to passing Objects around!

Comment: No worries - anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! As it stands the Call has too many parameters ... so I'll cut it down later.

```
Dim inputsheet As Worksheet
Set inputsheet = Worksheets("blah")

Call change_colour(Tgl_EHCP.Value, "Tgl_name", inputsheet.OLEObjects("Tgl_name"))

Public Sub change_colour(BooValue As Boolean, Tgl_butt As String, tgl_button As OLEObject)
'
' change button colour
'
With ActiveSheet
  Dim myCtrl As OLEObject
  If BooValue = True Then
     tgl_button.Object.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
     Else
     tgl_button.Object.BackColor = RGB(184, 204, 228)
  End If
End With
End Sub
```